# java xml annotation get field with namespace, <aaa:bbb>value</aaa:bbb>

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm working on a project that has no schema and I have to parsing the xml response manually.
My problem is i can't get some value using the xml annotation.

For example , the xml is like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<autnresponse>
    <action>QUERY</action>
    <response>SUCCESS</response>
    <responsedata>
        <autn:numhits>7</autn:numhits>
    </responsedata>
</autnresponse>
```

And the java class is :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "autnresponse")
public class AutonomyResponse {
    private String action;
    private String response;
    private ResponseData responsedata;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "responsedata")
public class ResponseData {
    @XmlElement(name = "numhits",namespace = "autn")
    private String numhits;
    @XmlElement(name = "totalhits")
    private String totalhits;
}
```

I can get the action and the response, but can't get the numhits in the responsedata, 
Can anyone tell me how to handle the `<autn:numhits>` using annotation? 
Too much Thanks !!!

***Another issue is : I have multi `<autn:numhits>` in the responsedata....how can i get all the value  in the Java code.***
--> I solve this multi same tags, just set List and the annotation will automatically generate the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is **autn** - is only prefix, not namespace. For correct processing of the XML document, namespace must be declared.

Right namespace declaration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<autnresponse xmlns:autn="http://namespace.here">
    <action>QUERY</action>
    <response>SUCCESS</response>
    <responsedata>
        <autn:numhits>7</autn:numhits>
    </responsedata>
</autnresponse>
```

You also need to change the annotation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "responsedata")
public class ResponseData {
    @XmlElement(name = "numhits",namespace = "http://namespace.here")
    private String numhits;
    @XmlElement(name = "totalhits")
    private String totalhits;
}
```

And finnaly advice for you. If you have a xsd scheme for this xml document, use the XJC utilit for java code generation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbah.html

Comment: Thanks Mark, actually there's no scheme :(   BTW,can't i use the prefix, and every time i should use the full URL for the namespace?It may be a little inconvenient....

Comment: Prefix is actually a variable. Variables name may change, but the namespace is always the constant.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB and other XML processors that are capable of processing XML Schema are going to treat everything before a `:` as a namespace prefix.  If the colon is then you can do the following.

**Java Model**

You need to specify that your element name contains the `:` character.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResponseData {

    @XmlElement(name = "autn:numhits")
    private String numhits;

    private String totalhits;

}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create a SAXParser that is not namespace aware
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        // Create the JAXBContext
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(AutonomyResponse.class);

        // Instead of Unmarshaller we will use an UnmarshallerHandler
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();

        // Do a SAX parse with the UnmarshallerHanlder as the ContentHandler
        xr.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);
        xr.parse("src/forum20062536/input.xml");

        // Get the result of the unmarshal
        AutonomyResponse autonomyResponse = (AutonomyResponse) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();

        // Marshal the object back to XML
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(autonomyResponse, System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Awakening - Specifying `autn:numhits` will work, but you have to use `UnmaeshallerHandler` as I've shown on the demo code.  The answer given by Mark is better if `autn` is supposed to be a namespace prefix.