# An invalid second ':' was found in the element type or attribute name

Tags: jaxb

```
class foo
{
  public static List parse(String input_xml)
        {
        try {
              // JAXB context created.
              JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
                ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(input_xml.getBytes());
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

              // Error comes while unmarshalling the input
                Root root = (Root) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(input);
                HashMap<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();

              //... Code to retrieve values from "root" and put it in list
                  }
              }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String input= "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
            +"<root>"
            +"<attribs R:SSB:12 = \"ABC\"/>" +
            "</root>";

        List list = parse(input);
    }
 }
```

1. "attribs" can contains multiple "attributes-value" pairs, hence i need to "UNMARSHAL" it     using Jaxb.
2. I tried using QName , but its throwing error.

Question : While parsing , I am getting this error : "An invalid second ':' was found in the element type or attribute name."  .... But i couldn't find any help .... attribute name and values are dynamic in my case.

Thanks for any help!!!*/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to feed JAXB with invalid XML:

```
<attribs R:SSB:12 = "ABC">
```

Colon symbol has special meaning in XML: it separates [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) and attribute (or tag) name under that namespace. That's why attribute (or tag) can only contain one colon.

If your attribute names are coming from elsewhere, you have to escape colons to make them valid XML attributes. Try replacing colons with dash symbol (`-`), for example:

```
<attribs R-SSB-12="ABC">
```

Comment: Thanks.... Kedder .
I really understood what you told, it was a good explanation, but, This XML(which i am hard-coding right now) is actually coming from some database in this particular form only. I need to parse it into list using jaxb.

Comment: Well, you have to pre-process that "xml" before passing it to JAXB. JAXB is using standard XML parser and it cannot digest such pseudo-xml -- you will not be able to get it parsed without modifying input. Consider detecting colons in attributes in your "xml" string and replacing them with something else (for example using regular expressions) before passing it to JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

The extra `:` is causing problems as by default JAXB expects the portion behind the `:` is the namespace prefix.  You can solve this by forcing JAXB to use a parser that is not namespace aware.

This can easily be done with a SAX parser and leveraging JAXB's `UnmarshallerHandler` as the `ContentHandler`.

**Full Example**

- [java xml annotation get field with namespace, <aaa:bbb>value</aaa:bbb>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062536/java-xml-annotation-get-field-with-namespace-aaabbbvalue-aaabbb/20069348#20069348)

Comment: Thanks Blaise!
But I tried with that code in the example. It's working fine, But returning me list containing {="ABC"} ....

**** But i want to retrieve  "R:SSB:12" name also and wanna put that in the list. How should i be doing that... ???