# XML to Java with JAXB unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm using the below code to unmarshal an XML to a set of Java classes (classes generated from an xsd).

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BlockType.class);
StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("C:\\Users\\Se\\Desktop\\watch2.xml");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<BlockType> je1 = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, BlockType.class);

BlockType cgwt = je1.getValue();
```

The XML that has to be unmarshalled has at its beginning a line like this one:

```
<test:MessageBlock xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/Watch/v2.1 Test_WatchSchema_v2.1.xsd">
```

If I remove the test: and xsi:.... the XML gets unmarshalled correctly. However, if I let them I get

```
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "test" for element "test:CargoWatchMessageBlock" is not bound.]
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an `xmlns:test` attribute in your XML document if there is an `test` prefix used.  Without that attribute declaring the prefix you should remove the prefix from your document for it to be valid.

---

### UPDATE

> I do not control the document so I guess I'll have to find some
>   workaround for removing the test: prefix and xsi: before
>   unmarshalling.

Below is a link to an example that should help you build what you are looking for.  It leverages JAXB's `UnmarshallerHandler` with a SAX parser to treat the prefix as parent of the element name.

- [java xml annotation get field with namespace, <aaa:bbb>value</aaa:bbb>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062536/java-xml-annotation-get-field-with-namespace-aaabbbvalue-aaabbb/20069348#20069348)

Comment: There is no such xmls:test attribute nowhere in the document.

Comment: @Sergiu - The document is invalid.  Do you control the doc so that you can fix it?  If not for a workaround is the prefix always the same?

Comment: I do not control the document so I guess I'll have to find some workaround for removing the test: prefix and xsi: before unmarshalling.

Comment: @Sergiu - I have updated my answer with a link to an example that should help with your workaround.