# JAXB Unmarshalling of Tag

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an XML file which is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<cpe-list>
   <generator>
    <product_name>National Vulnerability Database (NVD)</product_name>
    <product_version>2.25</product_version>
    <schema_version>2.3</schema_version>
    <timestamp>2014-06-12T03:50:01.201Z</timestamp>
  </generator>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:0.7">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 0.7</title>
  </cpe-item>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.2.5">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.2.5</title>
  </cpe-item>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.3.1">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.3.1</title>
  </cpe-item>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.4.1">
    <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.4.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"/>
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.4.1</title>
    <references>
      <reference href="https://code.google.com/p/sexy-polling/downloads/list">version information</reference>
      <reference href="http://2glux.com/projects/sexypolling">product information</reference>
    </references>
  </cpe-item>
</cpe-list>
```

I'm using JAXB parser to parse this XMl file.

How do i specify the annotation for this tag.

```
<cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.4.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"/>
```

Because this one is giving SAXException.

```
@XmlElement(name="cpe-23",namespace="cpe23-item", required=false)


[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/Downloads/NIST/random.xml; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 79; The prefix "cpe-23" for element "cpe-23:cpe23-item" is not bound.]
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:523)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:220)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
```

Comment: That XML is not namespace-well-formed (you haven't declared the `cpe-23:` namespace prefix) so I suspect JAXB will have difficulty handling it.

Comment: @IanRoberts even after providing namespace it is not working. Check i have edited.

Comment: cpe-23 is the namespace and cpe23-item is the tag (the name)

Comment: @pdem Even that has the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why You Are Getting the Error

In XML that corresponds to an XML Schema the portion of the name before the `:` is called the prefix.  The prefix isn't really part of the name, but instead refers to a namespace that is declared in an element like

```
 xmlns:cpe-23="http://www.example.com/cpe23"
```

In your case element name is just `cpe-23:cp23-item` and the namespace aware parser that JAXB is using is being thrown off.

### What You Can Do About It

You can parse the document with a SAX parser that is not namespace aware (the default) and specify a JAXB `UnmarshallerHandler` as the `ContentHandler` to do the object conversion.

- [java xml annotation get field with namespace, <aaa:bbb>value</aaa:bbb>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062536/java-xml-annotation-get-field-with-namespace-aaabbbvalue-aaabbb/20069348#20069348)

On your property you would specify the `@XmlElement` annotation like:

```
@XmlElement(name="cpe-23:cp23-item")
```

Comment: @XmlElement(name="cpe-23:cp23-item") @Blaise Doughan this gave the same exception.

Comment: @user1232583 - Did you do the part with the SAX parser and `UnmarshallerHandler`?  The link I have has a full example.